# mahotas can not save the actual converted image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, mahotas

```
import os
import mahotas
from PIL import Image
from pylab import *

path='all_images' 

for file in os.listdir(path):
  current = os.path.join(path, file)
  extension = os.path.splitext(current)[-1]
  fileType = extension.upper()


  if os.path.isfile(current):

    im = array(Image.open(current).convert('L'))

    # create a new figure
    figure()

    # show contours with origin upper left corner
    contour(im, origin='image')
    axis('equal')

    show() # This is showing contour image, I want to save this in the next line
    mahotas.imsave(current+'.png',im)
```

The show() command shows the figure of the converted image. But after that the figure can not be saved in the next line. I want to save the figure from the show command. Can anyone please help in this regard?

Answer (score 1):

This is not about mahotas, per se. `mahotas.imsave` will save its argument and you are passing it `im`, which is unchanged.

To save the contour you generated with `pylab`, you should look into [matplotlib.pyplot.savefig](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=savefig#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig):

```
savefig('contours.png')
```